# Regex for "after last /", "before possible ?", "last 32 characters"?

Tags: regex

How can I deploy a regular expression to match a string in a URL which may have several formulations?

In the example below, the string for matching happens to be "6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1"? It may be any 32 characters, always 32 characters.

I have been using `(.{0,32})((?=\?)|$)`, which I think means something like "last 32 characters after last slash, until either a question mark or the end" - but it's capturing two groups in examples 3/ and 4/ below, it should just capture the first.

1/ After last slash, ie ...

```
https://www.example.com/folder/6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1
```

2/ But not always immediately (ie could be 32 characters before end)...

```
https://www.example.com/folder/Extraneous-material-here-6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1
```

3/ Except, sometimes there will be a query string after the desired text (so, 32 chars before question mark, but a question mark is not always present)...

```
https://www.example.com/folder/6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1?v=593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033
```

4/ And sometimes there may be both a query string after **and** some extraneous text preceding...

```
https://www.example.com/folder/Extraneous-material-here-6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1?v=593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033
```

... with my current expression, this one is matching both 6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1 and 593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033.

Comment: You could *capture* that value using `([a-fA-F0-9]{32})(?:\?.*)?$` regex. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xk4mG9/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://www.example.com/folder/Extraneous-material-here-6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1?v=593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033 and https://www.example.com/folder/6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1?v=593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033 seem to incorrectly return the bit inc query string "6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1?v=593af44a9e9b4da6bb2ee491c949b033" (Match 1) and "6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1" (Group 1). Need just one match for 6c39b9cd8b5c4ae89aab69200a4608b1.

Comment: The regex matches correctly. That is what you need to access, Group 1 value. What is your programming environment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew iOS Shortcuts, whose Match Text action is regex. It's returning the full but including query string.

Comment: Maybe look at `(?:-|\/)(.{0,32})(?:$|\?)` and group 1.  Example: https://regex101.com/r/Md8R2i/1

Comment: Try `(?<!\w=)\b[a-fA-F0-9]{32}(?=\?|$)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xk4mG9/2). `(?<!\w=)` makes sure the query param values are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your regex mentions slashes. `.` matches any character and you are simply matching 32 of them before a question mark or end of string.

From your examples, it looks like you want 32 hex characters surrounded by a slash or dash and end of string or question mark.

```
(?<=[/-])[a-f0-9]{32}(?=\?|$)
```